# Extending vscode intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a custom js-doc attribute which contains the path to the dependency file.

eg: @dependency {import('loadash/somefile')}

Since this is simple string and error prone, I am looking for a way to extend vs-code import intellisense to this custom js-doc attribute. Vscode supports intellisense for standard js-doc attributes @type, @param and @typedef, would be great if there is a way to extend this behavior to my custom attribute.

[example of the intellisense for @type attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80d6c.png)

I looked at few extensions related to this, but none offer the rich experience vscode offers. Any pointers in this regard would be really helpful.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a [snippet](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) for a quick and dirty solution. A snippet will show the intellisense menu and insert a piece of code based on a prefix you enter. They are saved in a JSON file in your settings directory `~/.vscode` and would look something like this:

```
{
  "deprecated": {
    "scope": "javascript",
    "prefix": "@D",
    "body": "@Deprecated {import('${1:path}')}"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response Matt, I realized that my question was not clear, updated it with example. What I am looking for is the intellisense for the attribute value.

Comment: There's also the concept of [tabstops](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_tabstops), I've updated my answer to illustrate this. Pressing tab inserts the snippet and pressing tab again moves to the first tabstop and highlights the placeholder text for easy replacement.

Comment: Thank you Matt, I have tried your suggestion but it is not providing the intellisense for the path. I have added a screenshot of the path intellisense I'm looking for on my attribute.

Comment: No problem. This snippet solution won't provide intellisense for the path attribute, it's just a way to quickly insert code blocks. I think what you want will require a custom extension implementation given that you're using a custom js-doc attribute. You need to tell vscode the paths to include based on the context.

Comment: I looked at few extensions on how they are implementing the path intellisense support. Most of the extensions are building their own suggestions list. But I want to leverage the vscode inbuilt path intellisense experience as it is pretty decent and rich. Any idea if that's possible with extension? Thank you once again for the help.

Comment: I think it's possible for sure. See this [path autocomplete extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ionutvmi.path-autocomplete) for example.